# referencing files from hadoop dfs in map reduce

Tags: hadoop

For my map reduce job, I'm reading lines in my input file to get external file paths.  So my file that I'm using as input looks like:

```
/user/local/myfiles/temp1.png

/user/local/myfiles/temp2.jpg

/user/local/myfiles/temp3.txt

/user/local/myfiles/temp4.txt

....
```

And I want to perform some operation on those files.  I need to grab the file object from the string path I read in my map function.  My question is: where do I put the actual copy of those files so I can grab them?  Do I put them on the hadoop dfs?  When I put them on the local system, I get a file not found error but I get the same error when I put them on the hadoop file system (so every line in the input file is something like "/user/hadoop/input/temp1.txt").  I can get the file name, but I need to be able to get the image object or text file object from the path listed in the input file.  Is there some way I can access a file on the dfs (or local system) from my map function given just a string path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add them to the HDFS so that they are accessible from all Mappers. The following works for me (on 0.20):

```
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
        FSDataInputStream in = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = null;

        String file = context.getConfiguration().get(Constants.INFILE); 
        in = fs.open(new Path(file));
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
```

and I add the Constants.INFILE in the driver, in order not to hardcode the filenames into the code.